# How to calculate different speed averages based on an angle?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, angle

Here it goes, I am making a climbing system in a Unity project where depending on the direction your speed is changed. In my case it would be a speed of 1 for going up, 1.5 for sideways and 2 for going down.

This is how I calculate angles right now:

```
float angle = (Mathf.Atan2(this.characterController.GetAxisControlValue(CharacterAxisControl.Vertical), this.characterController.GetAxisControlValue(CharacterAxisControl.Horizontal)) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);
        angle %= 360.0f;
        if (angle < 0.0f)
        {
            angle += 360.0f;
        }
```

GetAxisControl value returns a vale between -1 and 1. Now I need to find out how you would get the average speed between point like this: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UmXv.png)

I'm searching for a formula that can solve this problem.

Could anyone assist me please, pretty please.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to e.g. know your `transform.localEulerAngles.x` ?

Comment: @derHugo considering I am not actually rotating the object itself I can't use that sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be proportional to the angle, then it's easy:

```
var speed = (angle % 180) / 180 + 1;
```

This will give you:

```
  0 deg   1
 90 deg   1.5
180 deg   2
270 deg   1.5
 45 deg   1.25
150 deg   1.83 // this is your picture example
```

If you want any arbitrary speeds you could use linear interpolation. Let's say you want speed `Vu` for going up, `Vs` for going sideways and `Vd` down.

```
var t = (angle % 180) / 90; // we only care about vertical direction
var speed = t < 1 
  ? Vu * (1 - t) + Vs * t         // this is for picking the value in the range 0..90
  : Vs * (2 - t) + Vd * (t - 1);  // this is in range 90..180
```

Comment: You're the best, thank you, i've never been good with math and algebra.

Comment: Bu what if I, for example, had a value of 2 a the top, 5 at the sides and 1.5 down?

Comment: It didn't actually, I updated the code a bit to fit into my script:    
`var t = (angle % 180) / 90; 
// we only care about vertical direction
var speed = t < 1 ? climbingUpSpd * (1 - t) + climbingSideWaysSpd * t         // this is for picking the value in the range 0..90
: climbingSideWaysSpd * (2 - t) + climbingDownSpd * (t - 1);`  

The values are (in this case) 1 for up, 5 for down and 1.5 for sideways but the result always ends up being 0.75, 1, 1.25 or 1.5  

Edit: I can't format holy f*ck, also, I can properly upvote you ^^

Comment: Alright so my bad, it almost works. I simply put the `var t = (angle % 180) / 90;` in the wrong spot. The only problem I currently have is the downward speed is at max 1.5 when it should be 5.

Comment: Probably because `climbingDownSpd * (t - 1)` is always 0.

Comment: when you go down t=2 because 180/90=2, so it will be `climbingDownSpd * (2 - 1)  == climbingDownSpd`